# Simplifying $\int_{0}^{1} y^2 \exp(ty^2) dy$

Tags: integration

I want to simplify the integral $\int_{0}^{1} y^2 \exp(ty^2) dy$. My attemp leads to the imaginary error function but is there another way to simplify it?

Comment: Are you looking for an anti-derivative or are there bounds (limits), for a definite integral?

Comment: There are limits. I edited my post.

Comment: the solution should be $$\frac{e^t}{2 t}-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \text{erfi}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)}{4 t^{3/2}}$$

Comment: This is were I got. Is there another way to simplify?

Comment: No, the erfi function isn't expressible in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Thank you for the reply